# How can I get notified about window get loaded in macOS Cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

So there is a modifier in SwiftUI called `.onAppear` which allow us to know the view get appeared, I am looking to same functionality in Cocoa macOS, so there is method in AppDelegate in Cocoa called `applicationDidFinishLaunching` so I am looking for something like that for Windows, let say I am looking something like `windowDidFinishLaunching`, so I just want window notify me when window did launch or shown, in my question I am lunching a window called about, so how can i know that about window get fully lunched and shown in screen? So the goal is to get notified when about window did lunch or fully shown in screen.

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var window: NSWindow!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
 
        buildMainMenu()
        
        buildWindow()
        
    }
    
    func buildWindow() {
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
    }
   
    func buildMainMenu() {
        
        let appMainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        
        let mainMenu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.submenu = NSMenu(title: "MainMenu")
        
        let mainMenuItem0 = NSMenuItem(title: "About", action: #selector(NSApplication.about), keyEquivalent: "a")
        mainMenuItem0.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Close", action: #selector(NSWindow.performClose(_:)), keyEquivalent: "w")
        mainMenuItem1.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem2 = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.shared.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q")
        mainMenuItem2.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        mainMenu.submenu?.items = [mainMenuItem0, mainMenuItem1, mainMenuItem2]
        appMainMenu.items = [mainMenu]
        
        NSApp.mainMenu = appMainMenu
        
    }
}


extension NSApplication {
    @objc func about() {
        AboutView().openInWindow(title: "About My App", sender: self)
    }
}

struct AboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.green
    }
}



extension View {
    
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {

        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
 
        return window
    }
}
```

By the way I am using a main file for lunching my application like this:

```
    import Cocoa

// **** Main **** //
let nsApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

Comment: Please define "fully lunched". Is the window itself updated or also its contents (which the window doesn't know)?

Comment: Maybe this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419552-didchangescreennotification

Comment: @Willeke: the window itself not the content of it.

Comment: @GerdK: yes something like one of those but not sure which one is the right one. Also the use case of it with my question.